# How to fetch a map with value as list in mybatis

Tags: java, mybatis, ibatis

I am trying to fetch a Map< X, List> from a mapper function in mybatis using annotations something like :

```
@Select("SELECT * FROM relation WHERE id = #{id}")
Map<X, List<Y>> getXYRelations(int id );
```

Using this I am getting a TooManyResultException, something like this :

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.TooManyResultsException: Expected one result (or null) to be returned by selectOne(), but found: 2
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectOne(DefaultSqlSession.java:63)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:95)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy51.getXYRelation(Unknown Source)
    at com.project.service.XYServiceImpl.getXYRelation(XYServiceImpl.java:548)
    at com.project.ee.test.JunitTest1.test(JunitTest1.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

So I added a mapkey something like this:

```
@Select("Select * FROM relation WHERE id = #{id}")
@MapKey("X")
Map<X, List<Y>> getXYRelations(int id);
```

but I am still getting failure with the following trace :

```
org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.PersistenceException: 
### Error querying database.  Cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
### The error may involve com.project.data.mapper.XYMapper.getXYRelation-Inline
### The error occurred while setting parameters
### SQL: SELECT * FROM relation WHER id = ?
### Cause: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.ibatis.exceptions.ExceptionFactory.wrapException(ExceptionFactory.java:23)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:104)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectMap(DefaultSqlSession.java:78)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectMap(DefaultSqlSession.java:74)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.executeForMap(MapperMethod.java:158)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperMethod.execute(MapperMethod.java:92)
    at org.apache.ibatis.binding.MapperProxy.invoke(MapperProxy.java:40)
    at sun.proxy.$Proxy51.getAllUsersWithRoles(Unknown Source)

    at com.project.ee.test.JunitTest1.test(JunitTest1.java:127)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:616)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:20)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:28)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:31)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runNotIgnored(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:79)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:49)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
Caused by: java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.wrapper.CollectionWrapper.findProperty(CollectionWrapper.java:42)
    at org.apache.ibatis.reflection.MetaObject.findProperty(MetaObject.java:86)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.applyAutomaticMappings(FastResultSetHandler.java:332)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.getRowValue(FastResultSetHandler.java:261)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleRowValues(FastResultSetHandler.java:214)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSet(FastResultSetHandler.java:186)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.resultset.FastResultSetHandler.handleResultSets(FastResultSetHandler.java:152)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.PreparedStatementHandler.query(PreparedStatementHandler.java:57)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.statement.RoutingStatementHandler.query(RoutingStatementHandler.java:70)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.SimpleExecutor.doQuery(SimpleExecutor.java:57)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.queryFromDatabase(BaseExecutor.java:267)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.BaseExecutor.query(BaseExecutor.java:141)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:105)
    at org.apache.ibatis.executor.CachingExecutor.query(CachingExecutor.java:81)
    at org.apache.ibatis.session.defaults.DefaultSqlSession.selectList(DefaultSqlSession.java:101)
    ... 33 more
```

I need List in the value somehow and I am not wanting to write a business logic for fetching a different list conveniently and converting it into the required as that will be of O(n) minimum. So can someone tell me something about this?

Comment: No answer from the community :(

Answer (score 1):

It should be

```java
@Select("SELECT * FROM relation WHERE id = #{id}") 
List<Map<String,Object>> getXYRelations(int id );
```